# Button not executing Django/Python script

Tags: python, django

In my home.html template:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"
          method = 'GET' action = '/action_name/' name="audio_record">Record Audio</button>
```

In my views.py:

```
def audio_functions(request):
    print('called function')
```

In my urls.py:

```
path('/action_name/', views.audio_functions, name='audio-record'),
```

what am i doing wrong?

Edit: I replaced the button with the suggested version below:

```
  <a href="{% url 'audio-record' %}" class="btn btn-dark"
    >Record Audio</a>
```

But I have a new problem. I actually don't want to redirect to by url/action_name. I just want to trigger the python script within the browser. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html :

```
   <a href="{% url 'audio-record' %}" class="btn btn-dark"
        >Record Audio</a>
```

and  urls.py

```
path('action_name', views.audio_functions, name='audio-record'),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py` you do not need the leading forward slash, as django adds this in automatically. Replace it with this and it should work:

```
path('action_name/', views.audio_functions, name='audio-record'),
```

Also the `method` and `action` attribues would normally go in the `<form>` tag, and not the `button` one. Also change `type` to `submit` on your button.

As @SALAHEDDINEELGHARBI says, you should really be using `{% url 'audio-record' %}` rather than hard-coding the url, however this is not the problem in this case (you shouldn't have a leading slash in `urls` as this would leave to a url with a double slash)

EDIT - In response to your edit:
You can't trigger a python script within the browser. It's a common misconception. Django is a web framework built in python, yes. But anything that happens in the browse has to happen in javascript. If you want to use python, you'll need to make a call to some django endpoint, do the python, and the send it back.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work (nothing prints in my terminal when i click the button)

Comment: @NBC I've update the answer. If it stil doesn't work can you add what is shown in the network section of your dev-tools, when you click on the button. What is the response code on the request? Does it send?

Comment: ok I got it to work, but I think I messed up originally. I actually don't want to redirect to by url/action_name. I just want to trigger the python script within the browser. Sorry and thanks so much for your help.

Comment: no worries, I've added an edit in reply to the edit you made in the question.

Comment: ah got it. Yeah I'm a rookie at this. Thanks for clarifying!